# Effects of not eating all my macros?

Tags: weight-loss, bodybuilding, body-fat, health, eating-habits

I've recently started to exercise and eat healthy. I started following my macro intake and surprisingly I have been eating much less of my supposedly daily values (almost always short on protein about 80g and about 20g of fat). I'm in a caloric deficit of around 700cals since my goal is to lose body fat. I'm not sure if I should eat even if I am not hungry in order to reach my macros, or if not reaching my macros is fine (but then is the caloric deficit too high).I am concerned of what might be the side effects of not even reaching my macro intake?

Using many youtubers and bodybuilding websites I have calculates my macros at:
Carbs= 205g
Fat= 80g
Protein= 200g
Calories= 2,340 cals
BMR= 3050 cals

I am 19 years old, 6'3", 225 bodyweight (around 200 lean body mass), and workout 3-4 times a week.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: No way to give an accurate answer if we don't know your goals.  Are you cutting, maintaining, or bulking?

Comment: Sorry, I'm cutting.

Comment: yikes I am trying to figure this all out. So I did the "Macro calculator" I am 5ft 1in and weigh in at 177. The calculator is telling me the following: Protein: 114g Carbs: 249g Fat: 53g Sugar: <50g Saturated Fat:<21g Calories: 1,869 Does this seem correct?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're on a cutting diet, I think that 3050 is a bit too high and seems more like a maintenance diet.

One of my issues with some of those equations online is the activity multiplier is too high based on the exercise you commit to during a week.  I can see how you'd get tired of eating over 3,000 kcals a day.

One trick that makes hitting your macros a little easier, instead of eating, is to drink them.  Put what you need in a blender and drink up!

I think a better starting point for you daily diet would be something like:

- 2573 kcals
- 257 grams of protein
- 257 grams of carbs
- 57 grams of fat

Start there and then adjust 50-75 calories at a time, plus or minus.  Weigh yourself every morning after you take care of business and before you eat or drink.  Take an average of your weight over 7-10 days, if it is going down, then you're on point assuming it isn't a radical drop.  Aim to lose about .5% to 1% of your body weight per week.

Another way to measure your fat loss (especially if the scale is playing tricks on you) is to get a tape measure and measure the widest part of your midsection.  If that number is shrinking every week, you're losing fat.

Also, take pictures every 10 to 14 days.  One front, one side, and one back and compare them to the previous pictures for a more visual comparison.

FINALLY:  **ALWAYS DO YOUR SQUATS AND ALWAYS HIT YOUR MACROS!**

Answer (score 1):

> Too little protein and you won't be building muscle/getting stronger
>   (and if you're seriously deficient it can lead to worse health
>   problems).
>
> Too little fat could throw off your sleep/mood, as fat helps regulate
>   horomones.
>
> Too few carbs leaves you feeling sluggish
>
> [/u/LiveAndLetLift](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fitness/comments/5ze7a6/tell_tales_signs_you_are_lacking_in_a_specific/dexe5xf/)

Here are some other gems from that thread:

> I was cutting hard a couple of summers ago, and like an idiot, I was eating around 30g of fat with abysmal saturated fats. I could not get an erection - you could have spawned Kim Kardashian butt ass naked in my room and nothing would happen. Fast forward to now, I eat loads of saturated fats and have my fat intake at around 90 - I'm keeping more muscle, have a sky high libido.
>
> /u/Kalashnikovxx

and

> If while shitting you are willing to confess to all manner of crimes to make the pain go away you could probably use more fiber.
>
> /u/Fitzmagics_Beard

Comment: Thank youso much for your great answer!! I will certainly have to adjust my nutrition

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your BMR works out to be that. Which could mean your off on every thing and actually losing a lot more than 700. Around about 1200 
 your BMR is around 2300- 2500

But your TDEE should be around 3500.. Work your macros to this and then remove the deficit in the fats and carbs. 500 is the best for fat loss..  so 250 for each works well 
So 27.7 g OFF fats 
And 62.5g OFF carbs

What I can work out from what your saying is this but thats based on your workout levels being 45-hr each time bringing your heart rate up to 60% capacity..and assuming your "job"is not in an office but standing or walking around for 7 hours a day << IF THIS IS NOT THE CASE THE FOLLOWING IS WRONG

your protein should be 225g Fats 108g and carbs 285g 
That's with the deficit taken off!  try hard not to go lower unless it's on fats and carbs and only by another 200-300 kcal

Always always try to hit proteins to keep muscle mass.. Counting macros is good as long as your doing it properly.

If your really struggling to get protein top up with a shake.. But dont substitute it.. Meats and fish plus nuts yoghurts and certain greens should still be fine to meet that target..

And finally I'm going to assume that your not 200lbs lean mass and trying to lose weight when only weighing 225.. 
If it is the case then you really really! need to be eating everyone of your macros plus some more! Before you drop to the floor.. Xxx

There are loads of ways to diet but  I found macros is the best way myself and it's very individual to you... Yes I just worked them out...just for you! So only you can follow it and get results..

So jack and Jill please don't follow the same thing! It's not meant for you and will not have the same affect xxxxx